# Хранит ли сервер полную историю «свежих правок»?

Tags: поддержка, правки

Наблюдаю следующую ситуацию:

- пользователь создаёт вопрос и публикует в нём пароль;
- через минуту до него доходит, что он сделал, и через правку стирает пароль;
- так как «grace period» ещё не прошёл, эта правка не видна на сайте, и другие пользователи не могут посмотреть исходную версию вопроса и увидеть пароль.

Понятно, что пароль уже успел засветиться в интернете (я его увидел до правки и запомнил, мухаха) и пользователю нужно его срочно менять, однако в дополнение к этому стал интересен вопрос: остался ли пароль храниться где-нибудь в базе данных? Или, может, он даже до сих пор виден модераторам? Или «свежие правки» объединяются на уровне БД и изначальный текст вопроса удалён с сервера безвозвратно (не считая логов sql-запросов и кэшей)?

Answer (score 6):

Про grace period:

1. Модераторы НЕ видят изменения, сделанные с постом в описанный период.
2. Про community manager'ов и хранение в базе ничего сказать не могу.
3. У комментариев нет grace period'а, модераторы могут видеть все правки.

Про перезапись:

4. Модераторы могут перезаписывать (redact) старые версии сообщений.
   Для этого требуется два разных модератора: один правит, другой утверждает.
5. С момента перезаписи старая версия НЕ доступна даже модераторам.
6. Про CM не знаю, однако в базе она точно хранится, так что при необходимости они могут получить её от разработчиков.
7. Для комментариев аналогичной функциональности нет.

Comment: Двое модераторов утверждают вроде?

Comment: @AK, разве? Мне казалось, один. Но вообще я только один раз пользовался сам и всего пару раз утверждал.

Comment: reduct это не опечатка?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, исправил.