# Оскорбительный вопрос был закрыт духом, хотя оскорбления нет

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, дух-сообщества

Набрел в очереди проверок на такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1507136). Суть закрытия такая:

> Это сообщение скрыто. Оно было отмечено как спам или оскорбительный
> материал и удалено 11 дней назад участниками...

хотя как по мне я ничего оскорбительного не вижу, даже после изучения истории правок. Безусловно такой вопрос может показаться кому-то глупым, и можно указать при человеческой проверке что-то типа "Необходимо конкретизировать", но точно как мне кажется здесь ничего нет оскорбительного в тексте. Но может я что-то не понял)

Comment: не знаю, применялся ли "redact" для этого поста, но это может что-то объяснить. [Модераторы могут перезаписывать историю сообщений](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9626/337980), и для резких оскорблений, спама, порнографии, и т.д. — это основное применение.

Comment: хм.... ну если там что-то было такого плана, тогда понятно, просто исходя из видимой истории правок ничего криминального я не увидел) вот и решил уточнить)

Comment: Понимаю. Я не обладаю этой информацией, просто это частое объяснение в таких ситуациях.

Comment: спасибо) посмотрим может ещё кто-то из вышестоящих коммент даст) просто интересно что с вопросом случилось)

Comment: Если верить логам, пользователь был удален как sockpuppet другого пользователя, который сейчас  в бане.

Comment: @Nofate само по себе это никак не делает вопрос оскорбительным ..

Comment: @Kromster затрудняюсь сказать, откуда именно такая плашка вылезла.

Comment: Возможно, из-за уничтожения участника вместе со всем его контентом.

Comment: я так вижу что сошлось вместе куча нюансов) в любом случае выглядит странновато этот вопрос :)

Comment: БЫло бы неплохо, если бы вы скрин оставили, а то не все могут видеть удалённые сообщения)